# Labels with lines to be filled by hand

Tags: addlines

Is there any way to replicate something like the image in latex? Labels with dashed lines to be filled with a pen by hand in the print paper. The spaces are not equal, só I don't know if it's viable to use a table.

[image]

Can you point any resources in this direction?w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `dashrule` package at your disposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\textsf{\bfseries Empress: }\enspace \hdashrule[-0.5ex]{130mm}{ 0.6pt}{2mm 1mm}

\end{document}
```

[image]